# SQL Server: combining multiple rows into one row from Merge UPSERT Counts

Tags: sql-server, merge, upsert

I am using SQL Server. I am using a `MERGE` statement to get the total rows updated, inserted and deleted when we compare source and target.

I have the result set as below from `MERGE` `OUTPUT` clause.

```
OUTPUT $action INTO @SummaryOfChanges;

SELECT Change, COUNT(*) AS CountPerChange  
FROM @SummaryOfChanges 
GROUP BY Change;
```

Result set:

```
Change       CountPerChange
---------------------------
UPDATED         10
INSERTED         3
DELETED          2
```

I would like to  save all three rows into single row as below:

```
Change 
--------------------------------------
UPDATE = 10, INSERTED= 3, DELETED = 2
```

OR if no changes:

```
Change 
-----------------------------------------
UPDATE = 0, INSERTED = 0, DELETED = 0
or 
UPDATE = 10, INSERTED = 0, DELETED = 0
```

I tried `STUFF` and `FOR XML` and `COALESCE` function too. I am not getting the result set as expected.

Please suggest the solution for this.

Thanks

Comment: Can you show the STUFF, FOR XML or COALESCE code you've tried - each of those approaches, or a combination to the same can work.  Maybe just needs a tweek.

Answer (score 0):

I can use case statements to pivot the data from rows into columns. The SQL below should give you a good idea on how to achieve what you want.

```
select
    sum(case when Change = 'UPDATED' then CountPerChange else 0 end) as UPDATED,
    sum(case when Change = 'INSERTED' then CountPerChange else 0 end) as INSERTED,
    sum(case when Change = 'DELETED' then CountPerChange else 0 end) as DELETED
from
    (
    select 'UPDATED' as Change, 10 as CountPerChange
    UNION ALL
    select 'INSERTED' as Change, 3 as CountPerChange
    UNION ALL
    select 'DELETED' as Change, 2 as CountPerChange
) t
```